# Prevent read access to other users' files using SELinux

Tags: php, permissions, nginx, selinux

While running a VPS for shared hosting, I put the data for the various users and websites as `/var/www/[USER]/public_html/[DOMAIN]/...`. I'd like to make sure that one user cannot access data from another user. I run NGINX + PHP-FPM on CentOS and I suppose the only way a user could access files is using PHP. I set the `open_basedir` setting in PHP to restrict access, as well as all `/var/www/[USER]` directories with `2750` permissions to prevent any user to enter that directory.

Is there a way to enforce this with SELinux, which to me seems a much more secure way to enforce this? I'd have to create a different SELinux user per system user? How would I configure the access policies and file contexts?

Comment: That isn't really even the _kind_ of thing SELinux does. SELinux is a complement to mandatory access controls (file permissions / ACLs), not really an alternate to them. If setting up the groups and group permissions correctly to restrict users to the correct files is too tricky, use ACLs (Access Control Lists) instead; then you can specific exactly which users have access to which files in an easy way.